# Signup page button isn't redirecting me to another page

Tags: javascript, html

```
<body>


<h1 style="color:red;">SIGN UP</h1>
<p style="color:blue;">Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>


  <label for="Email">Email:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email"><br><br>
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
<label for="repeatpassword">repeatpassword:</label>
  <input type="text" id="repeatpassword" name="repeatpassword"><br><br>
<button onclick="email" >SIGNUP!</button>

  

    <script>
var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;


function email(){
if(document.getElementById("password").value===document.getElementById("repeatpassword").value && email.include("@")== true){
location.href = "question2.html";
}

}




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to redirect to another html page when clicking on signup button and email input field contains "@" and password input field value is same as repeatpassword but I don't know what is wrong with my code

Comment: Should be `email.includes("@")== true` (notice the plural)

Answer (score 0):

Check out with `window.location.href` in the script function to redirect.
for more reference look out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. Button onclick="email()" parenthesis is required because you are calling a function on a button click.
2. Function can't access a variable declared outside the function. So declare that email var inside the function scope.
3. It's not email.include() function it's includes(). "s" was missing. Ref -
   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

```js
function email(){
var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
if(document.getElementById("password").value===document.getElementById("repeatpassword").value && email.includes("@")== true){
console.log("Working");
}
else{
console.log("Not working");
}

}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:red;">SIGN UP</h1>
<p style="color:blue;">Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>

   <label for="Email">Email:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="Email" name="Email"><br><br>
  <label for="password">password:</label>
  <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
<label for="repeatpassword">repeatpassword:</label>
  <input type="text" id="repeatpassword" name="repeatpassword"><br><br>
<button onclick="email()" >SIGNUP!</button>
```